# How using a pointer and definition from a #define in C

Tags: c, pointers, client, user-defined-functions

I was wondering exactly how the `gattCharCfg_t` within this defined snippet is being used.

Here is the #define snipped:

```
    // Client Characteristic Configuration table (from CCC attribute value pointer)
      #define GATT_CCC_TBL( pValue )           ( (gattCharCfg_t *)(*((PTR_TYPE)(pValue))) )
```

And here is how it is being accessed in a couple spots in the given code:

```
    // Characteristic Configuration: voltage
    static gattCharCfg_t *voltDataConfig;

      // Allocate Client Characteristic Configuration table
  voltDataConfig = (gattCharCfg_t *)ICall_malloc(sizeof(gattCharCfg_t) *
                                                    linkDBNumConns);
    if (voltDataConfig == NULL)
    {
      return (bleMemAllocError);
    }
```

I guess I am not understanding the mechanics of how it is being accessed. I would definitely appreciate a more thorough explanation as I am just diving back into c.

Comment: That line **doesn't** define `gattCharCfg_t`.

Comment: Also, look for the place in the code where GATT_CCC_TBL( .. ) shows up

Answer (score 2):

```
( (gattCharCfg_t *)(*((PTR_TYPE)(pValue))) )
```

1. `(PTR_TYPE)(pValue)` - cast pValue as a PTR_TYPE (pointer)
2. `*((PTR_TYPE)(pValue))` - look at the memory location pointed to by the pointer
3. `(gattCharCfg_t *)(*((PTR_TYPE)(pValue)))` - for a pointer pointing to a `gattCharCfg_t` structure (could be an array of `gattCharCfg_t`) instead of void *

`GATT_CCC_TBL` is a macro to shortcut having to write out the conversion. With respect to the other code in your post,

```
  voltDataConfig = (gattCharCfg_t *)ICall_malloc(sizeof(gattCharCfg_t) *
                                                    linkDBNumConns);
```

1. `sizeof(gattCharCfg_t)` - take the size of `gattCharCfg_t`, e.g., 23 bytes
2. `* linkDBNumConns` - multiply it by linkDBNumConns, e.g., 100 making 2300 bytes
3. `ICall_malloc(..)` - allocate that much memory
4. `(gattCharCfg_t *)` - cast that location in memory as a pointer to `gattCharCfg_t` structures

**Update.** Looks like this code is from the Bluetooth stack, in which case

```
typedef struct
{
  uint16 connHandle; //!< Client connection handle
  uint8  value;      //!< Characteristic configuration value for this client
} gattCharCfg_t;
```

So `GATT_CCC_TBL( pValue )` will take a pointer value `pValue` and *turn what it points to* to one or more gattCharCfg_t structures - most likely an array of these since _TBL is likely "table".

Comment: "*will take a pointer value `pValue` and turn it into a pointer to one or more gattCharCfg_t structures*" I'd say you miss one indirection here. It should read "*will take a pointer value `pValue` and turn what it points to into a pointer to ...*". Note the `*` in `(*((PTR_TYPE)(pValue)))`.

Comment: @alk, I agree with that

Answer (score 0):

In the code there is no use of the macro `GATT_CCC_TBL`<sup>1</sup> anywhere. The code is casting the return value of `ICall_malloc()` which presumably returns `void *`<sup>2</sup> to a pointer of type `gattCharCfg_t`<sup>3</sup>. If this is really [c](/questions/tagged/c) code that is actually not necessary and

```
voltDataConfig = ICall_malloc(sizeof(gattCharCfg_t) * linkDBNumConns)
```

and the better version would be

```
voltDataConfig = ICall_malloc(sizeof(*voltDataConfig) * linkDBNumConns)
```

would probably be correct.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Which is what `#define` defines actually.</sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub>You never need to cast `void *` to another pointer type in [c](/questions/tagged/c).</sub>
<sup>3</sup><sub>Note that `gattCharCfg_t` is actually a type defined somewhere with a `typedef`.</sub>